# Appending one URL to another as a link

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do (and failing miserably at it) is create a link...  and that link should open up a specific page with the current page appended to it.  For example... If the user is on a page called www.bar.com and click the link... he would go to www.foo.com?link=www.bar.com

Here is my sorry little attempt at this...

```
<img src="#" id="link" target="_blank">

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("link").href = 'http://www.foo.com?link='.window.location.toString();
}
</script>
```

I could do this in PHP but I can not use PHP for this particular page.  Can someone please help?

**EDIT:**  I completely botched up my question be cause I added code here that i was in the middle of editing on accident.  I was trying to alter that a href code to place a specific image in that place instead ...for example

```
<img src="#">
```

becomes...

```
<img src="http://www.bar.com?link=www.foo.com">
```

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: An `img` tag doesn't have a `href` attribute. You have to do this to an `a` tag.

Comment: please see my "edit" in the question...

Comment: see mine @Kartikeya Khosla updated ans it will work fine...

Answer (score 2):

It's best to wrap your img with a tag and then change its attribute : (and use + and not . for chaining strings ! )

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="myLink"><img src="#" ></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("myLink").href = 'http://www.foo.com?link='+ window.location.href.toString();
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok i already knew that but forgot to change that part of it in here.  My bad.

Comment: Yes, but the target attribute belongs to the a tag

Comment: yup, I've copied-paste the OPs code, fixed, anyway is question was totally changed..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <img src="#" id="link" target="_blank">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("link").src = 'http://www.foo.com?link='+window.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not working...   you see here is what I am trying to do.  You see, http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=http://www.google.com will show a qr code for google.com.  And I want a code that will automatically display the qr code for any page the user is on in my site.  So if you went directly to that URL i gave above, you'll see the qr for google.com... but I want javascript to generate this qr code automatically by inserting the current URL into the page instead of google.com.  I hope I didnt make that confusing.